# How can do multiple stationary tests for multiple timeseries in a dataframe

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following df:

```
head(vardata)
       Month repo Callrate  WPI GDP  FED    nse   usd
1 2001-04-01 9.00     7.49 5.41 4.6 4.50 1125.2 46.79
2 2001-05-01 8.75     8.03 5.60 4.6 4.00 1167.9 46.92
3 2001-06-01 8.50     7.24 5.30 4.6 3.75 1107.9 47.00
4 2001-07-01 8.50     7.19 5.23 5.3 3.75 1072.8 47.14
5 2001-08-01 8.50     6.94 5.41 5.3 3.50 1053.8 47.13
6 2001-09-01 8.50     7.30 4.52 5.3 3.00  913.9 47.65

vardata_num<-df[,2:8]
```

I want to conduct Box.test, adf.test, and kpss.test for all the 7 var with following set of rules:

Say I set a significance level of 5%. Then the rules are:

1) For the Box.test, if p-value < 0.05 => stationary

2) For the adf.test, if p-value < 0.05 => stationary

3) For the kpss.test, if p-value > 0.05 => stationary (note change of inequality)

Individually i did the tests as:

```
Box.test(ts(vardata_num$repo),lag=20,type="Ljung-Box")

    Box-Ljung test

data:  ts(vardata_num$repo)
X-squared = 1100, df = 20, p-value <2e-16

adf.test(ts(vardata_num$repo),alternative = "stationary")

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  ts(vardata_num$repo)
Dickey-Fuller = -2.7, Lag order = 5, p-value = 0.3
alternative hypothesis: stationary

kpss.test(ts(vardata_num$repo))

    KPSS Test for Level Stationarity

data:  ts(vardata_num$repo)
KPSS Level = 0.32, Truncation lag parameter = 3, p-value = 0.1

# to extract p values
Box.test(ts(vardata_num$repo),lag=20,type="Ljung-Box")$p.value
adf.test(ts(vardata_num$repo),alternative = "stationary")$p.value
kpss.test(ts(vardata_num$repo))$p.value
```

This was done one at a time for all the variables.....

But I would like to do all these tests in one go for all the var & the outputted in some sort of a data frame if possible maybe like this:

```
   var         box.pvalue  box  adf.pvalue adf  kpss.pvalue kpss
   repo          0.03      TRUE    0.03   TRUE     0.03    FALSE
   Callrate      0.03      TRUE    0.03   TRUE     0.03    FALSE
   WPI           0.03      TRUE    0.03   TRUE     0.03    FALSE
   GDP           0.03      TRUE    0.03   TRUE     0.03    FALSE
   FED           0.51      FALSE   0.03   TRUE     0.03    FALSE
   nse           0.03      TRUE    0.03   TRUE     0.03    FALSE
   usd           0.45      FALSE   0.03   TRUE     0.03    FALSE
```

Where TRUE= series is stationary ; FALSE= series is NON-stationary

## update--- my attempt

## stationarity tests for multiple time series

```
multi_stat_tests<- function(df){
  for(i in 1:dim(df)[2]){
    df_multi<-data.frame(var=names(df)[i],box.pvalue=Box.test(ts(df[,i]),lag=20,type="Ljung-Box")$p.value,adf.pvalue=adf.test(ts(df[,i]),alternative = "stationary")$p.value,kpss.pvalue=kpss.test(ts(df[,i]))$p.value,
box=Box.test(ts(df[,i]),lag=20,type="Ljung-Box")$p.value<0.05,
adf=adf.test(ts(df[,i]),alternative = "stationary")$p.value<0.05,
kpss=kpss.test(ts(df[,i]))$p.value>0.05
)
    return(df_multi)
  }
}

>multi_stat_tests(vardata_num)

  var box.pvalue adf.pvalue  kpss.pvalue  box  adf  kpss
1 repo          0     0.2859         0.1 TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

Its just picking up only one var......its not iterating across all the variables...missing something here....HELP required!!!!!

Comment: It's best to include what you've tried so far. You've outlined what you want to do, but what is it specifically that's tripping you up? It's much better that folks here show you how to adjust your code, rather than writing it for you.

Comment: @rosscova   I have done all these tests one at at time for each var separately.....I need assistance to do in a some sort of a loop.......

Comment: Post the code you've used for those "one-at-a-time" tests. Showing you how to iterate code you've already got will be a lot better than starting from scratch.

Comment: @rosscova   edited with tests incorporated ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `dplyr` and `tidyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tseries) # for kpss.test

data <- data.frame(Sys.Date()-1:200, matrix(rnorm(1400, 0, 1), ncol=7) )
colnames(data) <- c("Month", "repo", "Callrate", "WPI", "GDP", "FED", "nse", "usd") 

data %>% 
 gather(Series, Value, -Month) %>%
  group_by(Series) %>%
   summarise(
    box.pvalue = Box.test(Value, lag=20, type="Ljung-Box")$p.value,
    box = Box.test(Value, lag=20, type="Ljung-Box")$p.value<0.05,
    adf.pvalue = adf.test(Value, alternative = "stationary")$p.value,  
    adf = adf.test(Value, alternative = "stationary")$p.value<0.05,
    kpss.pvalue=kpss.test(Value)$p.value,
    kpss=kpss.test(Value)$p.value>0.05
  )
```

Long-table design allows you to avoid `for` loop solution. Instead, you conduct a conditional analysis (conditioned by `Series`) of values in column `Value.`

Comment: Fantastico!!!    Posting here the usual & not so effiecient way also....

Answer (score 0):

## Here is the usual and not so efficient way of doing the same

```
multi_stat_tests<- function(df){
    p <- ncol(df)
    df_multi <- data.frame(var=names(df),
                           box.pvalue=sapply(df, function(v) Box.test(ts(v),lag=20,type="Ljung-Box")$p.value),
                           adf.pvalue=sapply(df, function(v) adf.test(ts(v),alternative = "stationary")$p.value),
                           kpss.pvalue=sapply(df, function(v) kpss.test(ts(v))$p.value)
                           )
    df_multi$box <- df_multi$box.pvalue < 0.05
    df_multi$adf <- df_multi$adf.pvalue < 0.05
    df_multi$kpss <- df_multi$kpss.pvalue > 0.05
    row.names(df_multi) <- c()
    df_multi[,c(1,2,5,3,6,4,7)]
}

df2<-multi_stat_tests(vardata_num)
df2
##        var box.pvalue  box adf.pvalue   adf kpss.pvalue  kpss
## 1     repo          0 TRUE    0.28593 FALSE     0.10000  TRUE
## 2 Callrate          0 TRUE    0.06008 FALSE     0.01000 FALSE
## 3      WPI          0 TRUE    0.28803 FALSE     0.03910 FALSE
## 4      GDP          0 TRUE    0.04358  TRUE     0.06211  TRUE
## 5      FED          0 TRUE    0.43113 FALSE     0.01000 FALSE
## 6      nse          0 TRUE    0.02745  TRUE     0.01000 FALSE
```